# R rbind multiple dataframes with names stored in a vector/list

Tags: r

I have a list that references the names of multiple dataframes

df_list

```
[[1]]
[1] "df_1"

[[2]]
[1] "df_2"

....

[[10]]
[10] "df_10"
```

How can I run the rbind command referencing df_list so I don't have to reference every one of the 10 names.

```
all_df <- rbind(df_list)
```

Instead of

```
all_df <- rbind(df_1,df_2,df_3,df_4,df_5,df_6,df_7,df_8,df_9,df_10)
```

Comment: Do either of `all_df <- do.call(rbind, all_df)` or `all_df <- lapply(all_df, rbind)` work with your data?

Comment: No, do.call creates a df with one column and the names of the dfs, the other crashes. "object 'df_list' of mode 'function' was not found"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this may work.

Example data: a list with the name of the `iris` data frame, twice.

```
df_list<- list("iris", "iris")
df_list

[[1]]
[1] "iris"

[[2]]
[1] "iris"
```

Then use `as.name` to convert the strings to the variable names:

```
all_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df_list, as.name))
nrow(df)

[1] 300
```